# recipe commences before first target

Tags: makefile

Error : Makefile:12: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

My makefile:

```
objDir := obj
incDir := include
srcDir := src
binDir := bin
files := matrix palindrome encryption

define generateObject
    @nasm -f elf32 -o $(objDir)/$(1).o $(srcDir)/$(1).asm
endef

object: $(addprefix $(srcDir)/,$(addsuffix .asm,$(files)))
    @echo -n "Generating object files... "
    $(foreach file,$(files),$(eval $(call generateObject,$(file))))
    @echo "Done"
```

I read in a post that this could be due to unwanted whitespace/tab but i could not find any.

I tried `cat -e -t -v  Makefile` and the output was :

```
objDir := obj$
incDir := include$
srcDir := src$
binDir := bin$
files := matrix palindrome encryption$
$
define generateObject$
^I@nasm -f elf32 -o $(objDir)/$(1).o $(srcDir)/$(1).asm$
endef$
$
object: $(addprefix $(srcDir)/,$(addsuffix .asm,$(files)))$
^I@echo -n "Generating object files... "$
^I$(foreach file,$(files),$(eval $(call generateObject,$(file))))$
^I@echo "Done"$
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this makefile that I can see, and when I run make with it I get no error like that.  What operating system are you using?  What version of make are you using (run `make --version`)?

Comment: I'm using GNU Make 4.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is use of the `eval` function.  `eval` is used to parse *make* constructs, but you're passing it a shell command.  Consider this line:

```
$(foreach file,$(files),$(eval $(call generateObject,$(file))))
```

Each time through the list you'll call `generateObject` with a filename.  That will expand to a shell command; for example if `file` is *matrix* then `call` will expand to:

```
^I@nasm -f elf32 -o obj/matrix.o src/matrix.asm
```

Then you take that text string and pass it to `eval` which tries to read that as a makefile.  Note that the text passed to `eval` must be a complete and valid makefile in itself; it's like you invoked make recursively and gave it this string as a makefile, except that the result of parsing are applied to the current makefile.  You can't give eval just a part of a valid makefile (like one command line in a recipe) and have it insert that into the current makefile.  Because that line by itself isn't valid, you get this error.

Instead of running `eval` on the results you want to concatenate them into one shell command.  Try this:

```
define generateObject
  nasm -f elf32 -o $(objDir)/$(1).o $(srcDir)/$(1).asm
endef

object: $(addprefix $(srcDir)/,$(addsuffix .asm,$(files)))
        @echo -n "Generating object files... "
        @$(foreach file,$(files),$(call generateObject,$(file)) && ) true
        @echo "Done"
```

However, that's really not "the make way".  You don't want to build multiple targets within a single rule: that defeats the main point of make which is that it only rebuilds the files that are out of date.

You should write your makefile like this:

```
object: $(files:%=$(objDir)/%.o)

$(objDir)/%.o : $(srcDir)/%.asm
        @nasm -f elf32 -o $@ $<
```

You don't need the `generateObject` variable, or `call`, or `eval`, or even `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and advice.