# "recipe commences before first target" makefile error with self created open wrt package

Tags: openwrt

I am trying to create my own Open WRT package called 'azure'. So far, I have only created a Makefile in the `package/utils/azure` directory. When I'm trying to build the package with `make` in the Open WRT root directory, a `dump.txt` will be created containing:
`Makefile:44: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`

My Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=azure
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1

PKG_SOURCE_PROTO:=git
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=<URL TO MY GIT REPO>
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=<COMMIT HASH>

HOST_BUILD_DEPENDS:=curl/host
PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=curl/host
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/host-build.mk

CONFIGURE_ARGS += --recursive

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/azure
    SECTION:=utils
    CATEGORY:=Network
    DEPENDS:+=curl
    TITLE:=<MY TITLE>
endef

define Package/azure/description
 <DESCRIPTION>
endef

# Use CMake for building the git repo.
define Build/Compile
    #!/bin/sh
    mkdir $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/build
    pushd $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/build
    cmake ..
    make
    popd
endef

define Package/azure/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/azure $(1)/usr/bin/azure
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,azure)) # <-- Line 44, the line that generates the error.
```

I presume that it has to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826380). Since I use Open WRT and not really Make the way it's intended to be used, I don't know how properly rewrite the code. Could someone help me with this? Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is `BuildPackage` defined and what do you hope for the `eval` to produce or cause Make to do?

Comment: All I can tell is your `Build/Compile` looks off. There's none if that in packages using CMake I was able to find, see [v4l2rtspserver](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=feed/packages.git;a=blob_plain;f=multimedia/v4l2rtspserver/Makefile;h=9d442ec2e48926873a220ae3b67ffa6df48d771d;hb=HEAD) for reference. Are you following some tutorial?

Comment: @tripleee I had the assumption that `BuildPackage` was defined if all the non-optional variables are defined, using [this tutorial](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages) as reference. `eval` would then run `Build/Compile` and `Package/azure/install` and then return the output files.
@orhtej2 Thanks for the link. I changed the `Makefile` a bit [(view)](https://pastebin.com/g6WDCNag). I haven't changed the way the dependency works, as the dependency is already on the host system, following  [this tutorial](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages) (see 'Host tools required').

Comment: What it it that you're trying to achieve? `curl` doesn't seem to use `host-build.mk` hence I doubt it's a valid dependency. Also, you need to `$(eval $(call HostBuild))` when using `host-build.mk`, but why do you need it? I believe it's for tools that need to be built on host machine at some point.

Comment: You can always `grep -rl "host-build.mk"` and `grep -rl "cmake.mk"` in root of your openwrt checkout to search for Makefiles using these, hence get some inspiration.

Comment: [opkg](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=blob_plain;f=package/system/opkg/Makefile;h=f00e574de08d0f22d12b03895341c41f2a020933;hb=HEAD) is a nice, quite simple example of package using both `cmake.mk` and `host-build.mk`, including dependency on other host-built package.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. To give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve: The Makefile should get a git repository that uses CMake. The repository has [a submodule](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c) as dependency. That submodule uses CMake as well. The submodule needs curl on the host system. The git repo should create a system binary for the system that will built by Open WRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem!

A few things went wrong:

1. There is a difference between `curl` and `libcurl`. Should have been using `libcurl` instead.
2. `PKG_BUILD_DIR` is not defined. It is easier to get the source files in advance, instead of using git in the Makefile. When the source files are cloned or copied, it is clear what the `PKG_BUILD_DIR` will be.

I completely rewrote the Makefile and added a `define Build/Configure` section. I assume that the tools for (cross-)compiling and linking should have been defined in this section in order to start a compiling process. For example, a definition for the CXX compiler would be:

`CXX="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)g++"`

Another thing of good practice would be to define directories with absolute paths instead of using relative ones.